# Calling local SSIS package from C# console application

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I'm trying to run a local SSIS package from a C# console application. I've built both the package and the application using .Net 4.5.1 in VisualStudio 2012. When I say "local" I mean the SSIS package hasn't been deployed to a SQL Server; I'm just trying to call the .dtsx file from the file system. The SSIS package runs fine from within VisualStudio. Here's my code:

```
string pkgLocation = @"C:\Users\06717\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RMA_Data_Cleanup\RMA_Data_Cleanup\";
string pkgName = "Package.dtsx";
Application app = new Application();
Package pkg = new Package();
DTSExecResult pkgResults = new DTSExecResult();
try
{
    pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation + pkgName, null);
```

There's more after this, obviously, but the problem comes with the app.LoadPackage line. When I try to run it, this exception gets thrown:

The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

I've googled this error message, and I haven't found anything that seems to apply to my case. One thing that occurs to me is that maybe I'm calling the wrong dtsx file. There's another one in the obj\Development folder. I've tried calling that one too, but I get the same exception. Am I calling the right file? Is there something I need to do from within Visual Studio, other than build the package, before I can do this? (pkgResults = Success, BTW)

Comment: Seems that line with `Package pkg = new Package();` is redundant.  
For more information on the error - define IDTSEvents interface as described in [MS Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.idtsevents.aspx) or [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b5813ba2-84c4-4a13-b31e-40df66aea1cd/consuming-events-in-code?forum=sqlintegrationservices).

Comment: Add this IDTSEvents interface as a non-NULL second parameter of LoadPackage and get error details.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I'm still researching, but I'll post what I figure out (or more questions) when I'm done looking at the error details I'm getting from the IDTSEvents interface.

Comment: I solved my problem by adding the IDTSEvents interface to my code as you suggested. The error was caused by my having both SqlServer 2008 and 2012 installed on my machine. I uninstalled 2008 and then got an error about a missing dll, specifically Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS. It was there in my project's references, but I had to delete it and then reload it. However, be aware it may not be possible to run the above code using VS2012. I'm now getting another error message about a version mismatch on another dll (DTSRuntimeWrap). I'm still investigating how to accomplish what I want in VS2012.

Comment: You should review all DTS dll references in VS project. If you really had SSIS 2008, references could point to ver 2008 dlls, and having uninstalled SSIS 2008 - you have broken references.