# Calling local SSIS package from C# console application using DTSRuntimeWrap version 11 and VisualStudio 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I recently posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257233/calling-local-ssis-package-from-c-sharp-console-application). I'm refining my question somewhat based on very helpful input I received from Ferdipux (see comments). Put simply, I'm trying to run a local SSIS package (i.e., not one deployed to a SQL Server) from a C# console application. Both the SSIS package and the console application were built in VisualStudio 2012 using .Net 4.5.1. The pertinent piece of code is as follows:

```
string pkgLocation = @"C:\Users\06717\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RMA_Data_Cleanup\RMA_Data_Cleanup\";
        string pkgName = "Package.dtsx";
        Application app = new Application();
        Package pkg = new Package();
        DTSExecResult pkgResults = new DTSExecResult();
        try
        {
            DtsEvents events = new DtsEvents();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation + pkgName, events);
```

I was getting stuck at the app.LoadPackage line and discovered I needed to uninstall the SQL Server 2008 client portion I had installed on my machine. However, now when I run the app, I only get as far as the line:

```
Application app = new Application();
```

When I try to run this line I get the error message: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." I have a version of DTSRuntimeWrap on my machine, but it's version 11, not version 10. I suspect that version 10 was deleted when I uninstalled SQL Server 2008. Is that correct? If so, how do I change my code so that I can use version 11 of the DTSRuntimeWrap dll? Or is this no longer possible and do I need to deploy the SSIS package to a SQL Server and run it as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090(v=sql.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) (note this says it works for SQL Server 2012)?

Answer (score 0):

I would write a comment but I'm missing reputation.

I had a similar problem once. SSIS makes it easy to run into dependency hell, so make absolutely sure, you dev machine has the same SQL-Server Version installed as the one you are planning to deploy on.

Did you try to remove all the references you need for running the SSIS and then re-referencing them to your project? If Visual Studio is not offering them you could have a look at the SQL-Server 2012 installation folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I looked for the dll in the SQL Server 2012 files, but it's not there. I also tried removing all the DTS-related references in my project and re-adding them, but it didn't help. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is the Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap referenced in your project directly? It might be a dependency of another assembly. You could try .NetReflector to check all dependencies of assemblies plus you can have a look where they are stored on the hard-drive. Also have a look at the Web/App.config files. The wrong assembly might be referenced there.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended earlier, after SSIS 2008 uninstall - check SSIS dll references in VS project for dll versions. If referring to obsolete versions - remove this reference and add again - it will add it with current dll which would have correct version.

Comment: I've removed all the pertinent dll references and re-added them, but as I say in my question, the only version of Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap that I have on my machine is version 11, but my program wants version 10.

Comment: @Melanie, for this specific Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap dll you have to go to GAC folders and get it from there - it is somewhere at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly. It is a pita...

Comment: I've searched my entire C: drive for it. The only Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll I have is version 11, which, when I add it to my project's references, gives me the error message in my original question. So I'm stumped.

Comment: @Melanie, found at my dev station at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32 (or 64)\Mircosoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap\v4... Try to locate ir in GAC with `gacutil -l microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap`. And check .config file for direct reference to version 10.0 assembly.

Comment: There are no direct references in the config file and gacutil returns 0 files.

Comment: @Melanie, in that case I do not understand your statement "The only Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll I have is version 11". You should have it either on disk on local machine (where you build and execute you app) or at GAC on this machine. If this DLL is not found anywhere, app will fail and you need to install SSIS engine on this machine.